# monogdb get the percentage of win after grouping with count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongojs

i have data

```
{"id" :1,"win":100},
{"id" :1,"win":150},
{"id" :1,"win":10},
{"id" :1,"win":0},
{"id" :2,"win":100},
{"id" :2,"win":0},
{"id" :3,"win":100},
{"id" :3,"win":200},
```

i need to find the winning percentage of each id;
expected output

```
id: 1 winper:75
id: 2 winper:50
id: 1 winper:100

       totalwin  is no. of greatethan zero win
        totalnotwin  is no. equal to zero win
```

i got the below query

```
 db.winn.aggregate([
{
$group: { _id: "$id",
 totalnotwon: { 
         $sum:
                 { $cond: [ { $lte: [ "$win", 0 ] }, 1, 0] }
        } 
        ,
     totalwin: { 
     $sum:
     { $cond: [ { $gt: [ "$win", 0 ] }, 1, 0] }
     } 
    }
}

],function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
});
```

});

i got the result

as  id totlwon totlanotwon
    1    3        1
    2    1        1
    3    2        0

i need to caluclate the pecentage of win
expected 
 id totlwon totlanotwon  %
    1    3        1     75
    2    1        1     50
    3    2        0     100

win % logic  (100/(totlwon+totalnotwon))*totalwon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try out this query it may give the result as per your formula:

```
(100/(totalwon+totalnotwon))*totalwon
```

Query:

```
db.demo.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$id',
      total: { $sum: '$win' },
      totalnotwon: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $lte: ['$win', 0] }, 1, 0] },
      },
      totalwon: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $gt: ['$win', 0] }, 1, 0] },
      },
      total: { $sum: NumberInt(1) },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $floor:{$multiply:[{ $divide:[100,'$total']},'$totalwon']}
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: Am using Mongojs module Its shown  error  numberint not declared

Comment: Just try "total: { $sum: 1 }," by removing NumberInt,  for more accuracy I have added it.

Comment: getting empty response am uing node api to call this and quey. it seems like poject not able to access totlawin colunms

Comment: result doesnt have id

Comment: $floor:{$multiply:[{ $divide:[100,'$total']},'$totalwon']}  this given me answer thanks you very much